# Brightness jumps to 100% after log out/lock on freya stable (Fresh Installation)

Tags: brightness

My laptop screen's brightness shifts to maximum value (100%) when I try to re-login after logging out or locking the session. However, no such problem is seen after restart or shutdown (OS remembers the previous brightness value). So, its only after logout or lock that my screen brightness will be set to 100% automatically. Please help me to fix this.

I use elementary OS freya (fresh installation).

Answer (score 3):

This bug has been reported on Launchpad before, 
[100% initial brightness on boot [laptops]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1322725). Please mark it as "it affects me" , provide more informations to help the dev fix it or put a bounty on it so it can be fixed as soon as possible.

Comment: I don't get 100% brightness on boot. I get it only after logout or lock. May be a weird variant of that bug. Reported though.